# How to validate start date and end date in multiple datetime picker in html table?

Tags: datetime, struts2

Hi iterating database data with struts iterator with that i have added start date time picker and end date time picker. how many iteration takes place that much date pickers going to added. how to validate start datetime and end datetime 
Datetime picker fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/0Ltv25o8/

```
<s:iterator value="#session.subjectlist" status="resultstatus" var="sub">
 <td><s:property value="#resultstatus.count" /></td>
 <td><s:property value="subjectname"/>  <s:hidden name="subjects" value="%{subjectname}" /></td>
 <td>
 <div class='input-group date datetimepicker1' data-provide="datepicker1" >
<s:textfield name="examDate1" cssClass="form-control"readonly="true" id="divId%{#resultstatus.count}"/>
 </td>
 <td>
    <div class='input-group date datetimepicker2' data-provide="datepicker2">
    <input type='text' name="examDate2" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Do you want make the end date as read-only?

Comment: you need to add a submit button

Comment: why submit button??

Comment: No submit button is needed, don't worry. Just try to explain yourself better the next time